# Unexpected array value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pygame

Ok so here is my problem when i run the code as it currently is, it operates perfectly fine, little island spots generate in random spots all over my map and it works. But as soon as I change the values of the variables MAPHEIGHT or MAPWIDTH to anything that would not make a square map example:

```
    MAPWIDTH = 40
    MAPHEIGHT = 60
```

it gives me this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\MapGeneration\test.py", line 59, in 
    island()
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\MapGeneration\test.py", line 58, in island
    tilemap[rNx][rNy] = tile
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I figure the error has to be something wrong within def island(): but im not sure what could be the problem so i'm turning to you guys for help

```
    from time import sleep
    import pygame, sys, random
    from pygame.locals import *
    ##COLORS
    BLACK = (0,0,0)
    BROWN = (153,76,0)
    GREEN = (0,255,0)
    BLUE = (0,0,255)
    ## CONSTANTS REPRESENTING RESOURCES
    WATER = 0
    GRASS = 1
    DIRT = 2
    FOREST = 3
    ## DICTIONARY LINKING RESOURCES TO TEXTURES
    textures = {
                    DIRT : pygame.image.load('images/mountain.png'),
                    GRASS : pygame.image.load('images/grass.png'),
                    WATER : pygame.image.load('images/water.png'),
                    FOREST : pygame.image.load('images/trees.png')
                }
    ## game dimensions
    TILESIZE = 16
    MAPWIDTH = 50
    MAPHEIGHT = 50
    TILERECORDX = []
    TILERECORDY = []
    ISLANDCOUNT = 30
    #A LIST OF THE RESOURCES
    resources = [DIRT,GRASS,WATER,FOREST]
    #LIST TO CREATE TILEMAP
    tilemap = [[WATER for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]
    #set up display
    pygame.init()
    #SETS THE DISPLAY SIZE BASED ON THE SIZE OF THE TILES AND THE AMOUNT OF CELLS         SET OUT IN
    #MAPWIDTH MAPHEIGHT
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))

    def island():
        global TILERECORDX,TILERECORDY
        for cnt in range(ISLANDCOUNT):
            #chooses a spot on the map to start landmass
            rNx = random.randrange(1,MAPWIDTH)
            rNy = random.randrange(1,MAPHEIGHT)
            TILERECORDX.append(rNx)
            TILERECORDY.append(rNy)
            if rNx >= MAPWIDTH:#to keep islands from generating on the edges of the         map
                rNx -= 1
            elif rNy >= MAPHEIGHT:#to keep islands from generating on the edges of         the map
                rNy -= 1
                #chooses what tile type ends up there
            randomNumber = random.randint(0,30)
            if randomNumber <= 1 or randomNumber == 2:
                tile = DIRT
            elif randomNumber >= 3 and randomNumber <= 16:
                tile = FOREST
            elif randomNumber >= 17 and randomNumber <= 30:
                tile = GRASS
            tilemap[rNx][rNy] = tile
    island()
    while True:
        #get user events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
            for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]],(column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))        
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Did you try to print your tilemap ?

Comment: Does changing `tilemap[rNx][rNy] = tile` to `tilemap[rNy][rNx] = tile` fix it?

Comment: Yes! that fixed it! any reason why changing those around would fix that?

Comment: I'd need to concentrate on how you have set up `tilemap`

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in my comment `tilemap[rNx][rNy] = tile` working for a "square" array but not otherwise suggested the indexing was backwards (or the setup).

Using `tilemap[rNy][rNx] = tile` fixes it.

Why?

Consider how you set this up.

```
tilemap = [[WATER for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]
```

Let's think it through with some numbers.

Suppose `MAPWIDTH` is 2 and `MAPHEIGHT` is 3. We then have a list of three items (the height), which are also lists, each containing two items.

i.e.

- `tilemape[0]` is a list of `MAPWIDTH` things.
- `tilemape[1]` is a list of `MAPWIDTH` things.
- `tilemape[2]` is out of bounds.

You could reorganise the setup if you needed, or stick with indexing into a "row" (giving the  y coord first).